# Can a website directly interface with os? WebUSB? Access windows dism?

Tags: windows, web, webapi, webusb, dism

I am lucky and thankful to be home for the holidays, and I wish everyone who reads this the best! I have an annual habit of doing windows clean installs on many of my family members' pcs along with my own.

I use dism in cmd/PowerShell on windows to create custom images for certain pcs, like adding drivers, removing preinstalled windows apps, updating preinstalled programs, etc. I made a small little PowerShell script that helps in the process as it is very tedious. (I normally do this while watching TV or something else.)

That got me thinking. Google created [Android Flash Tool](https://flash.android.com) that sends commands to android devices directly from a website. It even can download new android images/builds and flash them to the device. I also stumbled upon [Simon Chan's WebADB.](https://github.com/yume-chan/ya-webadb)

Those two examples are pretty cool; massive kudos to the developers of both. I was just hoping for some rough ideas. Is running say dism.exe possible on the web? Like taking a cloud file (like Google's android images) and running dism to make some user-selected customizations?

This process would entail being like a web-based [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) by formatting and putting files on a user-selected USB Stick. (This should be possible?) However, the next step would require "talking to windows" and accessing dism.exe directly on the local windows machine. Then mounting an ESD/wim file that was just put on the USB stick, then making changes to it using dism, and then unmounting and committing changes to the stick. Would this be possible?

This is just a very early stage idea and would honestly probably be more hassle than it is worth. But I could totally work on it during my spare time just to learn. Frankly, before I should have asked the above questions, I should have asked:

1. Can a website talk directly to "windows."
2. Can a website say tell windows to unzip a file locally or zip a bunch of files?
3. Create folders or simple tasks such as writing files directly to a directory (without chrome/file explorer holding its hand)?

I have built websites before, I have used npm/node, angular, and familiar with Google Firebase/GCP. However, this seems more complicated and out of my knowledge base. Hilariously, I am a computing security/networking engineer, and I can't even begin to fathom the sheer amount of security issues that would be possible with something like this. The site basically needs access to run cmd/terminals on the client machine. The thought of that gives me nightmares.

As computing and, namely, the web continues to evolve with the advent of new APIs, PWAs, etc., it is interesting what one can do with a "simple" website. If what I am describing is not possible now, I hope that someday it can be—in a fully secure way.

Thank you to whoever reads this and responds! I am looking for a "yes/no, your crazy" and hopefully a rough description of how/what. However, I am open to anything! Thank you again.

Comment: 1. no. 2. no. 3. no.

Comment: @GuyIncognito | Haha, thanks for the comment! I didn't think so. Maybe someday hopefully. I look forward to other comments.

Comment: Sorry, but the only interesting evolution worth considering is what a website **cannot** do. When a major newspaper's front page starts serving malware you just know that you want less of that.

Comment: @IInspectable | I understand your point. However, there are many applications for websites directly interfacing with the operating system. It would allow easily accessible and portable versions of old local programs. 7zip could be converted into a website, removing any need to install and bloat the local os. Of course, this would take the website, browser, and os to secure the entire stack. Much like an app requests for location permission, or an application asks windows for permissions to make changes to the system. Lots of work would need to be put into this, maybe some day.